# can I use $_POST 2 times with different page?

Tags: php, html, post

can we use $_POST 2 times with different page ? 
this example ..

**action.php**

```
<form action="next.php" method="post">
<input name="test" value="test" />
<button type="submit" name="test">submit</button>
</form>
```

**next.php**

```
<?php
$test=$_POST['test'];
?>
<form action="next1.php" method="post">
<input name="test1" value="<?php echo $test; ?>" />
<button type="submit" name="test1">submit</button>
</form>
```

**next1.php**

```
<?php 
echo $test2=$_POST['test1']; >> in here i didnt get test1 value . why ?
?>
```

Comment: you want print both text field values in next1.php file?

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: @Michael Halomoan Sihoml ,Yes you can use $_POST in two times in your code..more details see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `next.php` and `action.php` you need to change your **input type** like as

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="test" />
<input type="text" name="test1" value="<?php echo $test; ?>" />
```

Within **next.php** and **action.php** you were missing the **type** `attr` of **input** tag

and you have same `name attributes` for `submit` and `input` within next.php need to remove or change the value from respective

```
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Comment: type attribute also not give in action.php so why does it work?

Comment: in action.php     <input name="test" value="test" />

Comment: I have addressed him towards the previous one also for the same

Comment: So, i think better to add next.php and action.php to your answer

Comment: I just tested it will work without type attribute, issue is with same name to text field and submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Below code i have tried my local server and it executed successfully.

**action.php**:-

```
<form action="next.php"  method="POST">
<input type="text" name="test"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**next.php**:-

```
<?php
$test = $_POST['test'];
echo $test;
?>
<form action="next1.php" method="POST">
<input name="test1" value="<?php echo $test; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**next1.php:-**

```
<?php 

$test2=$_POST['test1'];

echo "------".$test2;
?>
```

Hope this will help.I think this is achieved your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it within one file e.g. **index.php** then here is the code

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['test'])){
    if(isset($_POST['test_text'])){
        echo 'Output from NEXT: '.$_POST['test_text'];
    }
 }
 elseif(isset($_POST['test1'])){
    if(isset($_POST['test_text1'])){
        echo 'Output from NEXT1: '.$_POST['test_text1'];
    }
 }
?>
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr >
        <td style="width:50%;">
            <form action="" method="post" name="next">
            <input type="text" name="test_text" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['test_text']) ? $_POST['test_text']:''; ?>" />
            <button type="submit" name="test">submit test1</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td style="width:50%;">
            <form action="" method="post" name="next1">
            <input type="text1" name="test_text1" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['test_text1']) ? $_POST['test_text1']:''; ?>" />
            <button type="submit" name="test1">submit test1</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

You need to send the POST value with the second form again, e.g. in a hidden field, otherwise the value won't be sent.

Furthermore your submit button shouldn't have the same name as the input field you want the content from. So change the name of your submit button, e.g.:

action.php

```
<form action="next.php" method="post"> <input name="test" value="test" /> <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button> </form>
```

next.php

```
<form action="next1.php" method="post">
<input name="test1" value="<?php echo $test; ?>" />
<button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry friends, i didnt understand your answer. can you explaain with the code / edit my code ?

Comment: Sure, I will explain it a bit more clear. The submit button inside your next.php has the name `test1` and no value. It is listed after your input filed where the test value should be in. Because submit button and test value have the same name, but the submit button is listed at the end and has no value, you won't receive any value as $_POST['test1']. To "fix" it, rename your submit button as I did in the answer.